# PHP preg_replace image names

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace image names within a page by using preg_replace but I'm probably missing something with regular expressions.

For the sake of the example, I'll use the following page:
https://www.laurentwillen.be/circuits/circuit-autriche/alpbach/

So here is what I do:

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $metadata["page_id"] );
foreach ($media as $key=>$value)
{
    $old_image = explode("/",$media[$key]->guid);
    $old_image = $old_image[sizeof($old_image)-1];
    $old_image = explode(".",$old_image);
    $old_image = "/".$old_image[0]."/";
    $new_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($key,'tablet');
    $new_image = explode ("/",$new_image[0]);
    $new_image = $new_image[sizeof($new_image)-1];
    $new_image = explode (".",$new_image);
    $new_image = "/".$new_image[0]."/";
    preg_replace($old_image,$new_image,$content,-1,$count);
}
```

To spare you the trouble of guessing the variable values, here is what $old_image and $new_image represent for the page given higher:

$old_image values:

```
/alpbach-photo-1/
/alpbach-photo-2/
/alpbach-photo-3/
/alpbach-photo-4/
/alpbach-photo-5/
/alpbach-photo-6/
/alpbach-photo-top/
```

$new_image values:

```
alpbach-photo-1-900x600
alpbach-photo-2-900x600
alpbach-photo-3-900x600
alpbach-photo-4-900x600
alpbach-photo-5-900x600
alpbach-photo-6-900x600
alpbach-photo-top-900x281
```

The count for preg_replace returns

```
9
0
9
0
9
0
0
```

But in the end, nothing is replaced.

If I try manually this:

```
preg_replace("/alpbach-photo-3/","/alpbach-photo-1/",$content,-1,$count);
```

Nothing is replaced either.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) says:

> preg_replace() **returns** an array if the subject parameter is an
>   array, or a string otherwise.
>
> If matches are found, the new subject will be **returned**, otherwise
>   subject will be **returned** unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.
>
> So you need to store the result of preg_replace into some variable.

```
$result = preg_replace($old_image,$new_image,$content,-1,$count);
```

Comment: Thanks but the subject is not an array, it's a string containing the whole page. If I store the result in a variable, the variable outputs the content with no change. You can check on the example page, in the source code, look for DEBUG, you'll see the output of $content where nothing has been replaced.